# Nifi Hbase data insertion taking more space than original data

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-nifi

I am doing data transformation in realtime using Nifi and after processing data is stored in Hbase. I am using `puthbasejson` for storing the data in hbase. While storing `row key/id` i am using is `uuid`. But the original data size in nifi data provonance or in online tool for a single JSON is 390bytes. But for 15 million data the size which it is taking 55 GB, according to which the data size for single record is 3.9 KB.

So, I am not getting how the data is stored, why the data size which is stored in hbase is more than the original data size and how I can reduce or optimize both in Hbase and Nifi(if any changes required).

JSON:

```
{"_id":"61577d7aba779647060cb4e9","index":0,"guid":"c70bff48-008d-4f5b-b83a-f2064730f69c","isActive":true,"balance":"$3,410.16","picture":"","age":40,"eyeColor":"green","name":"Delia Mason","gender":"female","company":"INTERODEO","email":"deliamason@interodeo.com","phone":"+1 (892) 525-3498","address":"682 Macon Street, Clinton, Idaho, 3964","about":"","registered":"2019-09-03T06:00:32 -06:-30"}
```

Steps to reproduce in nifi:

```
generate flowfile--->PuthbaseJSON(uuid rowkey)
```

Update1:
data stored in hbase:
[image]

Comment: Can you query the hbase data to see what's actually there?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for the response!!,  I have updated the screenshot of the data stored in hbase by using scan command in the question.

Comment: Appears you are repeating data

Comment: no just for testing purpose I inserted same data with different rowkey multiple times

Comment: Okay, well, Hbase generates a row key and the string "details", plus a timestamp for each json key/value pair, so why would the size not be larger than your input?

Comment: but the behaviour which I saw is same data if I insert as a binary data for field values instead of string, it takes less memory than the above mentioned values.

Comment: And also, when I tested the size of single json=(size of table in bytes)/(number of packets). So, for 10,000 the value was 300 bytes, then for 10million, it was 3kb I am not getting why it is increasing. And for these table I have enabled snappy compression otherwise it takes more space than the above mentioned values.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main thing you may be getting surprised by is that Hbase stores each column of a table as an individual record.

Suppose your UUID is 40 characters on average, field 1, 2 and 3 may each be 5 on average and perhaps it adds a timestamp of length 15.

Now originally you would have an amount of data of size 40+5+5+5+15 = 70
And after storing per row as per your screenshot, with three columns it would become 3*(40+5+15)=180 and this effect can increase if you have smaller or more fields.

I got this understanding from your screenshot but also from this article: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-improve-apache-hbase-performance-via-data-s

Now the obvious way forward if you want to reduce your footprint, is to reduce the overhead. I believe the article recommends serialization, but perhaps it would also simply be possible to put the entire json body into one column, depending on how you plan to access it.